# Will shrinking a volume in Windows 7 delete the contents of that volume?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit on my laptop. I want to shrink down the C:\ volume to make room for a new partition that I'm going to put Linux Fidora on.

I don't want to do this if it's going to wipe the drive, obviously. Is it required that you do a backup before shrinking a drive, or does shrinking just use up the free space and not effect your files etc.?

[image]

Comment: No, shrinking the HDD does not remove files it just allocates the free space.

Comment: So it creates a new unallocated partition that can be used for a new OS?

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: And yet doing a full backup **is a really good idea(TM)**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem at all. If you have just C Drive, you can divide this into 4/5 drives as your wish.

Simply complete the operation as you shared in the image.

Shrink C Drive first (Enter the amount of space for C drive)
Then divide it again for D drive. Continue this way.

If you need any further help, please follow the link below:
[Create New Volumes without Partition](http://www.markspcsolution.com/2014/02/create-new-volumes-without-partition.html)